# Borel-measurable functions $R\rightarrow R$

Tags: measure-theory

For $f: R\rightarrow R$ this two proposition are identical ($B$ is Borel set).

1. $\forall A \in B\ f^{-1}(A) \in B$
2. if $A$ is open subset then $f^{-1}(A) \in B$

Is it true? And if it's then how can I prove it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider
$$
\Sigma:= \left\{A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}): f^{-1}(A) \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\right\}.
$$
Can you show it is a $\sigma$-algebra containing the open sets?

Hint 2: You are trying to prove that 2. implies 1. Assume $f^{-1}(A) \in B$ for all $A$ open. This tells you that the open sets are in $\Sigma$. Now can you show that $\Sigma$ is a $\sigma$-algebra? This should follow immediately from the fact that preimages behave nicely under any set operations.

Comment: Probably i didn't get smth. Can you explain is $A$ an subset of $\mathbb{R}$ or a point?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the $\mathcal{B}$'

Comment: It's obviously so for continuous $f$.

Comment: Check my hint 2.

Comment: "preimages behave nicely under any set operations"
I can't get why. If you can show it for all open (and closed) subsets it doesn't mean you can show it for all.

Comment: @Ximik The borel $\sigma$-algebra is defined to be the smallest $\sigma$-algebra which contains the open sets. If you show that $\Sigma$ is a $\sigma$-algebra which contains the open sets, it follows that $\mathcal{B}\subseteq \Sigma$ which implies that $f^{-1}(A) \in \mathcal{B}$ for all $A \in \mathcal{B}$.